# IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to get results from a pretrained model using coco2017 dataset, but I get the error below in my training loop:-

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
too many indices for tensor of dimension 0
  File "C:\Users\manoj\Downloads\FYP\OBJECT_DETECTION_V2.py", line 323, in <module>
    output = model(images,valid_targets)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 0
```

my **getitem** code where i make the targets:-

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        annotation = self.annotations[idx].copy()
        image_id = annotation['image_id']
        image_filename = "{:012d}.jpg".format(image_id)
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, image_filename)
        #print("Original target:", annotation)
        if not os.path.exists(image_path):
            print(f"Warning: Image not found - {image_path}. Skipping.")
            return None
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
        bbox = annotation['bbox']
        #print(bbox)
        if bbox[0] == 0 or bbox[1] == 0 or bbox[2] == 0 or bbox[3] == 0:
            print(f"Warning: Bounding box with x_min or y_min or width or height as 0 found. Skipping image.")
            return None
        if bbox is None:
            print(f"Warning: 'bbox' key not found in annotation {annotation}. Skipping.")
            return None
        category_id = annotation['category_id']
        #print(category_id)
        if category_id is None:
            print(f"Warning: 'category_id' key not found in annotation {annotation}. Skipping.")
            return None
        if self.transform:
            image, bbox = self.transform(image,bbox)
        else:
            image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
        print("Keys in annotation before assertion:", annotation.keys())
        extra_keys = set(annotation.keys()) - {'image_id', 'bbox', 'category_id'}
        for key in extra_keys:
            del annotation[key]
        print("Keys in annotation after assertion:", annotation.keys())
        #annotation['label'] = label
        category_name = self.category_id_to_name.get(category_id)
        if category_name is not None:
            #annotation['labels'] = category_name
            category_id = [category['id'] for category in categories_info if category['name'] == category_name][0]
        else:
            print(f"Category name not found for category ID: {category_id}")
        #labels_tensor = torch.tensor(annotation['labels'], dtype=torch.int64)
        #annotation['labels'] = labels_tensor
        assert set(annotation.keys()) == {'image_id', 'bbox', 'category_id'}, "Target keys modified during loading/transformation"

        # Check data types of target elements
        assert isinstance(annotation['bbox'], list), "Bounding box data type modified"
        assert isinstance(annotation['category_id'], int), "Category ID data type modified"
        bbox[2] += bbox[0]
        bbox[3] += bbox[1]
        bbox = torch.tensor(bbox, dtype=torch.float32)
        if bbox.dim() == 1:
            bbox = bbox.view(1, -1)
        # Convert category ID to tensor
        category_id_tensor = torch.tensor(category_id, dtype=torch.int64)
        category_id = torch.tensor(category_id, dtype=torch.int64)
        image_id = torch.tensor(image_id, dtype=torch.int64)
        target = {
            'boxes': bbox,
            'category_id': category_id,
            'image_id':image_id, 
            'labels': category_id_tensor   # annotation['labels']
        }
        return image, target
```

and my training loop:-

```
# Training loop
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")
    for batch_idx, (images, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        print(f"Batch {batch_idx}, Number of images: {len(images)}, Number of targets: {len(targets)}")
        for i, target in enumerate(targets):
            print(f"Target {i}: {target}")
            for j, bbox in enumerate(target['boxes']):
                print(f"Bounding box {j+1}: {bbox}")
        if len(targets) == 0 or len(images) == 0:
            print("Warning: Empty targets list. Skipping batch.")
            continue
        print(targets)
        print(type(targets))
        for t in targets:
            if isinstance(t, dict):
                print("dictionary target detected:", t)
        print(type(targets))
        print(len(targets))
        images = [image.to(device) for image in images]
        #targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} if isinstance(t, dict) else t for t in targets]
        # Move targets to device
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor) else v for k, v in t.items()} if isinstance(t, dict) else t for t in targets]
        print("Targets after conversion to device:", targets)
        for i, target in enumerate(targets):
            bbox = target['boxes'][0]
            print(f"Bounding box {i+1}: {bbox}")

        valid_targets = []
        for target_idx, target in enumerate(targets):
            valid_boxes = []
            for box_idx, box in enumerate(target['boxes']):
                # Check if width and height are positive
                if box[0] > 0 and box[1] > 0 and box[2] > 0 and box[3] > 0:
                    valid_boxes.append(box)
                    #print(f"target index {target_idx}, box index {box_idx}: {box}, width: {box[2]}, height: {box[3]}")
                else:
                    print(f"Invalid box at target index {target_idx}, box index {box_idx}: {box}, width: {box[2]}, height: {box[3]}")
    # Only add targets with valid boxes
            if valid_boxes:
                target['boxes'] = torch.stack(valid_boxes)
                valid_targets.append(target)
        print(f"valid targets: {valid_targets}")
        
        #valid_indices = []
        #for i, item in enumerate(valid_targets):
        #    if 'boxes' in item and len(item['boxes']) == 1:  # Assuming each item has only one box
        ##        box = item['boxes'][0]
        #        if len(box) == 4:
        #            x_min, y_min, width, height = box
        #            if width > 0 and height > 0:
        #                valid_indices.append(i)
        #            else:
        #                print(f"Invalid bounding box at index {i}: {box}")
        #        else:
        #            print(f"Invalid bounding box at index {i}: {box}")
        #    else:
        #        print(f"No valid bounding box found at index {i}")

        #valid_targets = [valid_targets[i] for i in valid_indices]

        if not valid_targets:
            print("Warning: Empty valid targets list. Skipping batch.")
            continue

        # Forward pass
        output = model(images,valid_targets)

        # Extract predicted bounding boxes from the output
        pred_boxes = output['boxes']
        
        # Extract predicted labels from the output
        pred_labels = output['labels']

        # Extract target bounding boxes from the targets
        target_boxes = [t['boxes'] for t in valid_targets]

        # Extract target labels from the targets
        target_labels = [t['labels'] for t in valid_targets]

        # Calculate IoU loss
        iou_loss_value = iou_loss(pred_boxes, target_boxes)
        
        # Calculate cross-entropy loss for labels
        labels_loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(pred_labels, torch.cat(target_labels))
        
        # Total loss (you may want to combine it with other losses)
        total_loss = iou_loss_value +  labels_loss

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        total_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print(f"Batch {batch_idx}, Loss: {total_loss.item()}")

    lr_scheduler.step()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {total_loss.item()}")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not using a debugger, I guess.

Comment: i did use multiple print statements after posting this but still no luck. i keep getting the same error.